# Nginx - how to restrict outbound traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

**Setup**

AWS load balancer forward requests from example.com/(internalIP) to a pool of nginx.
Nginx will have to grab that url (example.com/internalIP) and forward the request to that specific "internalIP".

The nginx pool need to have internet access (security tool installed on the nginx ec2 needs it) so I can't restrict the aws security group of the nginx pool to a specific subnet of private ip's.

**PROBLEM**

Given that setup I need to find an nginx configuration that will only forward to a specific subnet of private ips. This will avoid access to our infrastructure using any private ip

Comment: You keep using the word "redirect" when I think you mean "forward". Forward is when a server sends traffic on to another server. Redirect is when the server responds to the browser to tell the browser that it should go somewhere else.

Comment: edited! Thx for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with this:

```
...
                  location ~* regexPattern {
                      ...
                      proxy_pass http://\$1:<PORT>/\$4;
                  }
              }
...
```